# Taking a set of values with a equal or similar mean in R

Tags: r

I am working with R.

I have two sets of values. They look like this.

```
setA     setB 
 .88      .55
 .67      .45
 .25      .35
 .40      .18
 .50      .05
 .70      .90
 .40      .25
 .57      .27
 .69      .21
 .90      .30
```

I took five values of the setA...

```
setA
.88
.40
.90
.57
.70
```

The mean of this set of words is 0.69.

Is there a way to select values of the setB that will have the same or very similar mean to 0.69?

So, I need a "random" sample of setB that will end up with a mean equal or around 0.69.

(In reality I have 800 values in setA, so is very difficult to select the values of the setB by just looking at them).

Comment: Sounds like an integer linear programming problem, which you can solve by lpSolve package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lpSolve/index.html). 
But integer programming can be slow for a large input size.  Do you need a rigorous optimum, or approximation is accepted?

Comment: approximation is accepted. @KotaMori

Comment: With or without replacement? Do the data follow/approximate a common distribution (maybe show a histogram and provide the mean/variance)?

Comment: How many values are in your setB?

Comment: I have a total of 400 per column, but I need only 20 of those. @jblood94

Comment: **800 per column @jblood94

Comment: @Ajrhmamd Ok. How about replacement? Do the setB columns tend to follow a common distribution (e.g., uniform, beta)?

Comment: I don't understand the question but I can sample 50 random data of the column. @jblood94

Comment: @Ajrhmamd. Don't worry about the question about the distribution--it might've helped, but it's not necessary. When you take your 5 values sampled from `setB`, do you sample with replacement (i.e., do you want to be able draw the same value more than once)?

Comment: well, the same value might repeat in the column, but the value of the row X cannot be repeated. I other words, if I have in the row number 3 a values of 0.30, and this values is taken, then the value of row 3 cannot be taken again. But If I have a value of 0.30 in row five we can take this value again. So, the same value can appear more than once, but the value of a row cannot be taken twice.

Answer (score 0):

One dangerously ineffecient approach, especially if you have large sets that doesn't only have 2 decimals, could be just random sampling in a while-loop.

```
exact_match <- function(setA, setB) {
  mean_setA_sample <- mean(sample(setA, 5))
  mean_setB_sample <- 0
  setB_sample <- c()
  iterations <- 0
  while (mean_setB_sample != mean_setA_sample) {
    setB_sample <- sample(setB, 5)
    mean_setB_sample <- mean(setB_sample)
    iterations <- iterations + 1
  }
  print(iterations)
  print(setB_sample)
  print(mean_setA_sample)
  print(mean_setB_sample)
}

close_match <- function(setA, setB, difference) {
  mean_setA_sample <- mean(sample(setA, 5))
  mean_setB_sample <- 0
  setB_sample <- c()
  iterations <- 0
  while (abs(mean_setB_sample-mean_setA_sample) > difference) {
    setB_sample <- sample(setB, 5)
    mean_setB_sample <- mean(setB_sample)
    iterations <- iterations + 1
  }
  print(iterations)
  print(setB_sample)
  print(mean_setA_sample)
  print(mean_setB_sample)
}
```

**EDIT**
I've updated to functions and included a solution for a close match.